# Allowing dot character in RewriteRule .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to allow dot in this rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/?$ index.php?D1=$1&D2=$2&D3=$3 [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/?$ index.php?D1=$1&D2=$2 [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/?$ index.php?D1=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

If I use this one:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+)/?$ index.php?D1=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

The value of D1 in the root directory is "index.php" instead of an empty value.

Any ideas about this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Its maybe not obvious, but if you think about it you will get it. The Point is you already have an internal rewrite rule in place.

So if you open your website `example.com` you actually get `example.com/index.php`.

Now you add some custom rewrite rule. The First one have no dot include so `index.php` do not match, but the second one have a dot include so `([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+)` will match also `index.php` and therefore will rewrite it to `index.php?D1=index.php`.

#### How to fix it?

Very simple: exclude index.php like so:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?index\.php
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+)/?$ index.php?D1=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Comment: Hi Webdesigner thanks! But if I use a second condition, stops working! I updated the question.